# How can I use scaleanimation in code-behind of uwp?

Tags: uwp

Here is the XAML:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Background="#1558b9" Name="WelcomeBorder" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5"></ScaleTransform>
                </Border.RenderTransform>                
</Border>
```

And I wanna to use a animation to make its ScaleX from 0.5 to 1.
What's more,I found microsoft provide ScaleAnimation as this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.animationmetrics.scaleanimation


But after I using the namespace of Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics in code-behind,it still can not use the ScaleAnimation.


It seems there is not Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics.dll in my project.And where can I find it?


My windows 10 version is 1803.


I know many people will ask me why do not use animation in XAML only but code-behind.That's beaucase I need play some animation one by one,and after all the animation complete then show the new page.

Comment: show your code behind part

Comment: @Muzib Firstly I can't find the reference of  Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics.dll so that visual studio always report that ScaleAnimation is not exist.Secondary microsoft's tutorial seems not telling clearly how to use it.So that I can hardly write a code in code-behind now.

Comment: @Muzib And also I googled but found nothing example about the ScaleAnimation of UWP,so sad about that.

Comment: If you are trying to animate the ScaleX or ScaleY of that `WelcomeBorder`, you should try Storyboard animation, not AnimationMatrics. I can provide you the code that will animate the Scale of that Border with Storyboard anination if you want

Comment: @Muzib Oh,If I mistake not,that ScaleAnimation is not for Storyboard animation,but for something else,right?I just want Storyboard animation for ScaleX and I think the way using ScaleAnimation is right before you told me yet .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, what you're looking for is to Storyboard a [DoubleAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation) rather than a ScaleAnimation.

To your literal question: if you look at the ScaleAnimation documentation you linked, the Device Family in the requirements section shows this needs the Desktop Extension SDK. You'll need to add that to your project references to use the ScaleAnimation. Again though, the ScaleAnimation metric probably isn't what you need here. It's for examining animations not creating them.

The ScaleTransform.ScaleX property is a double, so you'll use a DoubleAnimation to animate it. Typically one defines the animation in Xaml and then [triggers it from code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations#starting-and-controlling-an-animation) rather than defining it completely from code, but you can do the latter if you really want to. See the [Storyboarded animations docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations) for an overview and the [Xaml Animation library sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Animations-f758de70/view/SourceCode) for a demo of creating a DoubleAnimation in Xaml and triggering it from code. While you're in the [Motion docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/uwp/design/motion/) the [Page Transitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/uwp/design/motion/page-transitions) and [Connected Animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/uwp/design/motion/connected-animation) pages are worth a read and may be useful for your overall cross-page animation scenario.
Also check out the [Optimize animations, media, and images docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations#starting-and-controlling-an-animation). You're on the right track targeting ScaleX. That's one of the specific recommendations made to avoid dependant (and therefore slow) animations.